# Save date in database with rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I'm new to rails so this is probably a newbie question, but I didn't find any help for this problem anywhere...

Let's say I have a database containing "stories" here. The only column are the title and a timestamp :

```
  create_table :stories
    add_column :stories, :title, :string
    add_column :stories, :date, :timestamp
```

I have a form in my views so I can create a new story by inputing a title :

```
<%= form_for @story do %>
  <input type="text" name="title" value="Story title" />
  <input type="submit" value="Start a story" />
<% end %>
```

I have this on my controller :

```
  def create
    Story.create title:params[:title]
    redirect_to "/stories"
  end
```

And the model 'Story' works fine.
So, when I create a new story, everything looks fine. My goal however is **to be able to sort the stories by date** (hence the :date timestamp).
**How can I make it so the current date is stocked in the :date timestamp, so I can sort my items by date ?**

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having to recreate the table from scratch, in terminal run 'rails g migration add_timestamps_to_stories' 
 - find the newly created migration file, make sure it has the following:

```
def change
  add_timestamps :stories
end
```

Run rake db:migrate

This adds two new columns, created_at and updated_at, you'll be able to sort by created_at from that point. Be sure to update previous records that don't have a created_at date (since it'll be nil) so you don't run into errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
def create
  Story.create(title:params[:title], date: DateTime.now
  redirect_to "/stories"
end
```

Comment: this is only if you want to create a story with a date at the time of creation. This is also a default column in model migrations `(:created_at)`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to track the creation timestamp of your story records, you could do it like this in your migration:

```
create_table do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.timestamps
end
```

In addition to your title field, this would create "created_at" and "updated_at" fields which are handled by ActiveRecord for you, like Andrew Kim suggested.